# How do I get the short name of an entity in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How does Symfony2 determine the short name of a Doctrine entity?

For example `Acme\DefaultBundle\Entity\User` becomes `AcmeDefaultBundle:User`.

What about `Acme\DefaultBundle\Entity\Group\UserGroup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Acme\DefaultBundle\Entity\Group\UserGroup` would be `AcmeDefaultBundle:Group\UserGroup`.

The part of the short name after the colon, is just appended directly to the converted namespace.

From `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory`:

```
protected function getFqcnFromAlias($namespaceAlias, $simpleClassName)
{
    return $this->em->getConfiguration()->getEntityNamespace($namespaceAlias) . '\\' . $simpleClassName;
}
```